# Exchange 2013 - Enable auto reply per mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, auto-reply

Our Exchange 2013 server is set up with only the default `*` remote domain, which has `AutoReplyEnabled` set to `False`.

I would like just a handfull of mailboxes to be able to send auto-replies externally, but retain the default behaviour for all others.

Is there a way of assigning another `*` remote domain to these mailboxes? Or can I set `AutoReplyEnabled` to true on the remote domain, but control auto-reply behaviour per mailbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to re-enable Auto Replies by setting `AutoReplyEnabled` to `True` and then use Transport Rules. The Transport rule should block messages of type `Automatic reply` with an exception of the Mailboxes you'd like to exclude, ideally by Group Membership.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, you could also allow users to send automatic reply to only internal by setting the parameter "**-ExternalOofOptions**" of **Set-Mailbox cmdlet** to **InternalOnly**(More details about the cmdlet "**Set-Mailbox**": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps). Hope it's helpful to you too.